# debugging REST API calls

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I made a small client app based on RestSharp. How I can debug HTTP RESP API calls? I like to see raw HTTP protocol (pretty formatted as option) My idea is to have something similar to console output in the POSTMAN app...

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Please expand.

Comment: Take a look at [Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic)

Comment: Swagger is a great tool though we had trouble getting it to work with Identity Server authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve tried several tools, but Fiddler is the winner for me. Thanks Phuzi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Requestbin](https://requestbin.com/) to trace your HTTP calls made by RestSharp or anything else.